# Understanding this query further

Tags: mysql

All,

Via much research, I have managed to get the following query to work, however I don't fully understand what it's doing. I now need to adapt it a little, hence need to understand it more thoroughly.

The query looks in several tables to provide a list of results with one row per group of results as opposed to having one row per result (which would have too much duplication of information)

The query is:-

```
SELECT od_date, tbl_order.od_id, tbl_order_item.od_item_id, pd_code, item_code, pd_name, >cust, pd_type, tbl_order_item.od_item_id, tbl_order_item.test_suite_name,
MAX( IF( tbl_lab_item.test_name = 'Test 1', tbl_lab_item.test_result, NULL ) ) AS TEST1,
MAX( IF( tbl_lab_item.test_name = 'Test 2', tbl_lab_item.test_result, NULL ) ) AS TEST2,
MAX( IF( tbl_lab_item.test_name = 'Test 3', tbl_lab_item.test_result, NULL ) ) AS TEST3,
MAX( IF( tbl_lab_item.test_name = 'Test 4', tbl_lab_item.test_result, NULL ) ) AS TEST4,
MAX( IF( tbl_lab_item.test_name = 'Test 5', tbl_lab_item.test_result, NULL ) ) AS TEST5,
MAX( IF( tbl_lab_item.test_name = 'Test 6', tbl_lab_item.test_result, NULL ) ) AS TEST6
FROM tbl_item 
INNER JOIN tbl_item ON tbl_lab_item.od_item_id = tbl_item.od_item_id
INNER JOIN tbl_order ON tbl_order.od_id = tbl_item.od_id
WHERE tbl_order.od_date LIKE  '%$orderDate%'
AND customer_id = '%custID%'
GROUP BY tbl_lab_item.od_item_id
```

This give me the following output:-

```
Order Date | Order ID | Item Id | <snip - other columns> | TEST1 | TEST2 | TEST 3 ...etc
09/09/2013 |    2     |    1    |                        | 10    | 20    | 30  ...etc
```

What I want to do now is display any result which is less than 50 as '< 50' rather than have the actual number displayed. Ditto for '>100'.

I'm not sure how to add this logic into the above query, or even whether it is possible.

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Jason

Comment: Do you want all tests (TEST1 TEST2 etc..) to be checked for being less than 50? Should all of them be less than 50, or just one is enough?

Comment: That's a good question. At the moment, all of them, however I suspect that the next step may be to have different levels for each test, so TEST1 may be <50 but TEST2 would be <60. My experience is that retaining the flexibility is usually the best way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you would want to wrap your existing query into another one such as...

```
select
      PQ.*,
      case when PQ.Test1 IS NULL then '     '
           when PQ.Test1 < 50 then '< 50'
           when PQ.Test1 > 100 then '> 100'
           else PQ.Test1 end as FinalTest1,
      case when PQ.Test2 IS NULL then '     '
           when PQ.Test2 < 50 then '< 50'
           when PQ.Test2 > 100 then '> 100'
           else PQ.Test2 end as FinalTest2,
      case when PQ.Test3 IS NULL then '     '
           when PQ.Test3 < 50 then '< 50'
           when PQ.Test3 > 100 then '> 100'
           else PQ.Test3 end as FinalTest3,
      case when PQ.Test4 IS NULL then '     '
           when PQ.Test4 < 50 then '< 50'
           when PQ.Test4 > 100 then '> 100'
           else PQ.Test4 end as FinalTest4,
      case when PQ.Test5 IS NULL then '     '
           when PQ.Test5 < 50 then '< 50'
           when PQ.Test5 > 100 then '> 100'
           else PQ.Test5 end as FinalTest5,
      case when PQ.Test6 IS NULL then '     '
           when PQ.Test6 < 50 then '< 50'
           when PQ.Test6 > 100 then '> 100'
           else PQ.Test6 end as FinalTest6
   from
      ( Your Full Query ) as PQ
```

Follow-up per comments

If your query is getting any record, then my version should too.  From your original query to deal with the column renaming, I would adjust

FROM

```
MAX( blah blah ) AS TEST1,
```

TO

```
MAX( blah blah ) AS preTEST1,
```

Same for columns Test2-6

Then, change my above query from

```
  case when PQ.preTest1 IS NULL then '     '
       when PQ.preTest1 < 50 then '< 50'
       when PQ.preTest1 > 100 then '> 100'
       else PQ.preTest1 end as Test1,
```

etc for 2-6.  The rest of my original query remains unchanged otherwise... It is still relying on results from your query.  You can also EDIT your existing post and put your revised query there for me to look at.  If the inner portion query returns nothing, then my outer query won't either.

Comment: I'm trying this one in phpmyadmin prior to writing it into the PHP, and the query is accepted, but I get no result lines. Any thoughts please?

Comment: I can't specifically say why.  This is just wrapping the results of your query.  Your inner query is doing the grouping and where clause and results in the given columns.  I am just taking THAT result and adding on the extra 6 columns for the FINAL display value of the respective tests.  Does your query by itself actually return records per the order date and customer?  If no records from that, so too will no records from my wrapped query.

Comment: Good point, well made. I had an error in the query which returned no results. It was to do with the date range, so I removed that element, and it works now and lists the columns as I would like them to be (i.e. < 50 etc) although the original columns are there as well. Presumably, I need to remove a part of the query to stop this being displayed, but I haven't found out which bit yet. Thank you though, so far this is great. I'll let you know where I get to next :)

Comment: @Jason, you need the preliminary "Test1-6" fields to create the "FinalTest1-6" columns.  If your code is expecting to work with the "Test1-6" columns, just change the inner query to something like "preTest1-6" and have the outer query refer to "PQ.preTest1-6" and have THOSE columns end as "Test1-6"

Comment: Fabulous, thank you. I shall give that a go. I've been playing with the syntax, but it either drops the columns completely, or duplicates still appear. I'll try what you suggest and report back.

Comment: I've changed the inner query to preTest1-6 as per your message, and am not getting the preTest result listed as well as the post test. I am putting the 'preTest' reference in the AS of the MAX statement in the original query, and then the Test in the AS of the PQ. case. Is this where you meant please? Thanks again, Jason

Comment: @Jason, revised answer with comment/clarification

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response, I got caught up in funding issues for the company. Thank you all for your help, and DRapp - this has worked sufficiently. I need to play around a little more but have got what I need from your very well explained answer. I have tidied up the rest in the PHP until I have time to try more. Thanks again, and huge apologies for leaving it so long to mark it answered!! J

Answer (score 0):

try using case for each column that you need to check
some thing like

```
case 
    when  result <50 then '<50'
    when  result > 100 then '..'
end
```

Comment: Whereabouts should I insert the case? Would it be after each MAX statement?